# Can't RDP Into EC2 After Running Systems Manger Command

Tags: amazon-ec2, domain, remote-desktop, aws-systems-manager

I ran a very simple powershell script (setting up odbc) on a bunch of EC2 instances using AWS Systems Manager.  The script worked but now I am unable to RDP into any of the instances.

I have tried start/stop/reboot, as well as running the troubelshoot rdp automation in systems manager, but no luck. The servers are still up and are processing jobs.

It may be worth noting that these instances are attached to to a domain.

I am pretty lost, would greatly appreciate any help!

Here is the error:

[image: RDP: An internal error has occurred]

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the script so that we can examine it? or atleast snippets of the code?

also i found this which might help with a stopgap to help you rdp back in:

[Windows 10 Pro, RDP Server, "An internal error has occurred"](https://serverfault.com/questions/934026/windows-10-pro-rdp-server-an-internal-error-has-occurred)

if not you can always ask the AWS support, i had a similar situation to you and they responded very well to this scenario.